# I want to replace '\' with '/'

Tags: javascript, replace, path

I want to replace '\' with '/' in JavaScript.
I have tried:

```
link = '\path\path2\';
link.replace("\\","/");
```

but this isn't working.
Am I doing this wrong?
If yes what's the correct way?

Comment: You're probably better off using node's built-in ability to use platform-appropriate delimiters in paths. By the way, what is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: How are you storing your string using single backslashes? Your path is going to escape the letter `\p` twice and the closing single quote `\'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Return_value) **returns** a string. Strings can't be mutated so it doesn't update the string in place.

> Return Value
>
> A new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.

You need to reassign the return value of the replacement to your `link` variable.

```
var link = '\path\path2\';
link = link.replace('\\', '/');
```

Additionally, when you use strings as the matching pattern, the `replace()` function will only replace the first occurrence of the characters you're trying to replace. If you want to replace all occurrences, you need to use regular expressions (regex).

```
link = link.replace(/\\/g, '/');
```

the `/ ... /` is a special way of encapsulating a regular expression in Javascript. The `\\` is is the escaped backslash. Finally, the `g` at the end means "global", so the replacement will replace *all* occurrences of the `\` with `/`. Here is a working example.

```js
var link = '\\path\\path2\\';
link.replace(/\\/g, '/');
console.log(link);
```

### Update for 2020

Around 2020 [`String.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) was introduced which does the same thing as the regular expression above, but using normal string literals.

```
link = link.replaceAll('\\', '/');
console.log(link);
```

Comment: Might be important to mention that `replace` only replaces the first occurrence when you give it a string, too.

Comment: @Ryan I've updated my answer to include this and an explanation of regex for doing global replacement.

Comment: yes that replaces only first occurrence.
is their any way to replace all at once.